# Command line mvn parameter to stop spring-boot-maven-plugin from executing run

Tags: maven, jenkins, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I'm developing a Spring Boot application and as part of the Integration Test phase of my maven project, I have configured the spring-boot maven plugin to start up and shut down during the pre and post integration test parts of the build as follows:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>post-integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

However, I did this just so that my developers can run their tests against a local instance of the service. On Jenkins, I would run the tests against an external service where I had deployed the service and I do not need the Spring Boot application to be spun up within the Jenkins job.

Is there a way for me to explicitly stop the spring-boot maven plugin from starting up the service via a mvn command line override?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can expose a property for it, something like

```
  <properties>
    <skip.it>false</skip.it>
  </properties>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>start</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <skip>${skip.it}</skip>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>post-integration-test</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>stop</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <skip>${skip.it}</skip>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Once you have that, run your command as follows: `mvn verify -Dskip.it=true` and the Spring Boot application will not be started as part of your integration tests.